# Vue Draggable - Dynamically Change Component After Drag/Drop

Tags: vue.js, vuedraggable

I have two separate dragAreas and when I drag components from one area to another, how can I dynamically change the status of my component based on the area it was dragged to?

Currently, I'm rendering the status from the serializer but I want to change it dynamically after drag/drop.

```html
<draggable
  class="dragArea published"
  :options="{ group: { name: 'g1', put: 'g1'}, animation: 120 }"
  @end="onEnd">
    <div
      v-for="lesson in classroomLessonsPublished"
      :class="`lesson-card ${lesson.id}`"
      data-status="published">   
        <div> 
          {{ lesson.status }}
        </div>
    </div>
</draggable>

<draggable
  class="dragArea unpublished"
  :options="{ group: { name: 'g1', put: 'g1'}, animation: 120 }"
  @end="onEnd">
    <div
      v-for="lesson in classroomLessonsUnpublished"
      :class="`lesson-card ${lesson.id}`"
      data-status="unpublished">   
        <div> 
          {{ lesson.status }}
        </div>
   </div>
</draggable>
```

Comment: You could use [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)

Comment: How do I identify which area the component has been dropped to so that my dynamic component will display the correct status?

Answer (score 5):

The `draggable` component emits a [change](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#events) event:

> `change` event is triggered when list prop is not null and the
>   corresponding array is altered due to drag-and-drop operation.

The argument passed to the event has a property called `added` which contains information of an element added to the array.

```
{
  newIndex: number, // the index of the added element
  element: T // the added element,
}
```

---

Example: You drag and drop an element from the published group to the unpublished group.

template:

```
<draggable
  class="dragArea unpublished"
  :options="{ group: { name: 'g1', put: 'g1'}, animation: 120 }"
  @change="onUnpublishedChange"
  @end="onEnd"
>
  <!-- ... -->
</draggable>
```

script:

```
 methods: {
    onUnpublishedChange({ added }) {
      if (added) {
        added.element.status= false // Not published
      }
    },
  }
```

---

Your groups have the same name, you should probably change that to:

Published:

```
:options="{ group: { name: 'published', put: 'unpublished'}, animation: 120 }"
```

Unpublished:

```
:options="{ group: { name: 'unpublished', put: 'published'}, animation: 120 }"
```